# UIPageControl show on top of UIImageView

Tags: ios, pagecontrol

From this example I can add the pageControl, but the pageControl is at the bottom of the screen.

How can I make it in the bottom, but on top of the image?

I want the image to be full screen, and the page control on top of the image.

the example code is :

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

i try to relocate the pageControl with the following code, but not success:

```
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,500,320,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting something like this to your needs:

```
 @interface ViewController () 
 {
     UIPageControl *pageControl;
 }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"soccer.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,480)];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];

    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(turnPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 }


-(void)turnPage:(UIPageControl *) page
{

    switch (page.currentPage) {
        case 0:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
            break;

        case 3:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            break;

        case 4:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        case 5:
            pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```